# Configuring a postgres server

Tags: postgresql, roles

I am configuring a postgres database on a server where multiple users should be able to login to. On this server there are multiple other databases. Some users should not be able to see these databases. I found out a way to not make them accessible for the users that should not have access to these databases. It would be even better if I could hide them to the view of the users login.

I have been scouting the internet for a while now so I decided to just ask the question. I assume it is possible but I cant find a good description of how to do it.

Comment: You can't hide the list of available databases. Even if a user doesn't have access to a database, the fact that it's there can not be hidden

Comment: It might be supported in future via row-level security on system catalogs, but at the moment you're out of luck. You'll learn more by searching for discussions on "multi-tenant" PostgreSQL instances.